# Return true is return false? Magic

Tags: c++, arm, openbsd

I have problem in my C++ program for extracting audio from VoIP packets.

It works well on Linux and OpenBSD on amd64 and x86 but when I run program on OpenBSD on ARM it does really magic things.

I call return true in LoadConfigFile and in ProcessConfiguration is result false.

Can anyone please help me? Maybe I am only really blindman. I did many testing prints in code.

This is main fucntion of program which calls function ProcessConfiguration.

```
int main ( int argc, char **argv ) {

    if ( ! config.ProcessConfiguration( argc, argv ) ) {
        std::cout << "process configuration failed" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "exiting whole program with EXIT_FAILURE" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::cout << "process configuration is true" << std::endl;

    // User want to only print configuration
    if ( config.m_printconfig == true ) {
        config.PrintConfig();
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    .
    . // Long uninteresting code
    .
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is function ProcessConfoguration which calls LoadConfigFile.

```
bool TConfig::ProcessConfiguration ( int & argc, char ** & argv ) {

    // Scan options from command line
    int c;
    while (( c = getopt ( argc, argv, "c:dhn" )) != EOF ) {
        switch (c) {
        case 'c':
            m_configfile = optarg;
            break;
        case 'd':
            m_daemon = false;
            break;
        case 'h':
            m_printusage = true;
            return true;
        case 'n':
            m_printconfig = true;
            break;
        default:
            return false;
        }
    }
    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;

    if ( LoadConfigFile() == false ) {
        std::cout << "LoadConfigFile was false" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    std::cout << "LoadConfigFile was true" << std::endl;
    return true;
}
```

And this function loads configuration file a parses all directives.

```
bool TConfig::LoadConfigFile ( void ) {

    std::string line;
    std::string directive;
    std::ifstream data;

    if ( m_configfile.empty() ) {
        m_configfile = DEFAULT_CONFIGFILE;
    }

    std::cout << "opening file " << m_configfile << std::endl;

    data.open( m_configfile.c_str() );

    if ( ! data.is_open() ) {
        std::cerr << "Couldn't open config " << m_configfile << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    std::cout << "configfile is open" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "before getline" << std::endl;
    while ( getline( data, line ) ) {
        std::cout << "after getline" << std::endl;
        trim_whitespaces( line );
        .
        . // Long uninteresting code
        .
    }
    std::cout << "before data.close" << std::endl;
    data.close();
    std::cout << "before return true in LoadConfigFile" << std::endl;
    return true;
}
```

And this is output on terminal.

```
$ ./call-extract -c call-extract.conf -d -n 
opening file call-extract.conf
configfile is open
before getline
before data.close
before return true in LoadConfigFile
LoadConfigFile was false
process configuration failed
exiting whole program with EXIT_FAILURE
$ echo $?
1
$
```

I call return true in LoadConfigFile and in ProcessConfiguration is result false.

Comment: Are you asking about the `echo $?` returning 1? A process that exits successfully will have an exit status of 0.

Comment: Without even saying what you expect and minimal code to reproduce what's going on your question isn't very useful. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask first.

Comment: I know that. My program exits 1 on return EXIT_FAILURE in main function.

Comment: I am sorry. The main problem is that I call return true in LoadConfigFile and in ProcessConfiguration is result of this function false.

Comment: What happens if you try bool TConfig::ProcessConfiguration ( int & argc, char ** & argv ) { return true; }

Comment: Maybe in the "long uninteresting code" there is some bug that corrupts the stack; in this case anything could happen afterwards, including receiving false when true was returned. Have you tried feeding your code into valgrind?

Comment: in Long uninteresting code in only big switch (15 cases) and there are only stored values in struct TConfig.
I asked my supervisor of bachelor thesis to add valgrind in this ARM (BeagleBone Black) with OpenBSD and he didn't find solution.

Comment: If there's such possibility, change method return value from `bool` to `int` and try it as a workaround. If there's still `0` instead of `1`, then I give up.

Comment: It is same with `bool` or `int`.

My tip is on function `getline`, because configfile really exists, is open, has 16 lines and first debug print after getline is never executed.

Comment: Before entering `while` loop ensure no error state on ifstream with: `data.rdstate() & std::ifstream::goodbit`

Comment: Now this is fail. Thank you. Now I have to investigate why is set bad or failbit.

Comment: So I changed `std::ifstream` with C++ `getline` to `FILE *`, `fopen`, `fclose` and C `getline` and now it works fine, but I don't really know why :-O

Comment: Do you have static destructors (ctors/dtors) and/or `atexit()` type libraries or functions.  They may alter the exit code as `main()` is not the final thing to execute.

Comment: No, I have never used these things yet. Problem is that I call `data.open( "filename" );` and failbit is immediately set. With `FILE * data = fopen( "filename", "r" );` it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Returned true is true.

Output for me:

```
before return true in LoadConfigFile
LoadConfigFile was true
```

Code without uninteresting parts:

```
struct TConfig
{
    bool ProcessConfiguration()
    {
        bool rv = true;
        if( !LoadConfigFile() ) { rv = false; }
        printf("LoadConfigFile was %s\n", rv?"true":"false" );
        return rv;
    }

    bool LoadConfigFile ( void )
    {
        printf("before return true in LoadConfigFile\n");
        return true;
    }
};
void fv()
{
    TConfig config; config.ProcessConfiguration();
}
```